# Perl: JSON::XS Is it possible to force boolean decoding as 1/0?

Tags: json, perl, boolean, decoding

Package JSON::XS uses JSON::XS::Boolean objects to represent true/false. Is it possible to force decoding true/false json values as 1/0 Perl numbers?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use JSON::XS;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json = decode_json(join('', <DATA>));
print Dumper $json;

__DATA__
{
    "test_true": true,
    "test_false": false
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'test_true' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::XS::Boolean' ),
          'test_false' => bless( do{\(my $o = 0)}, 'JSON::XS::Boolean' )
        };
```

I want something like this after decode_json:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'test_true' => 1,
          'test_false' => 0
        };
```

Reason: In some cases, it's hard to predict how JSON::XS::Boolean will be serialized with, for example, SOAP serializer or another one.

[PerlMonks discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1058198).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Those objects correctly evaluate as true and false within Perl.

Comment: You're using `Dumper` , have you tried just printing `$json->test_true` and `$json->test_false` ? They get correctly stringified to `1` and `0`

Comment: @ChatterOne that would be `$json->{test_true}` and `$json->{test_false}`. `$json` is just a hash, you cannot call methods on it.

Comment: I recommend that you use [`Cpanel::JSON::XS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS) instead, which is compatible (except that the bugs in `JSON::XS` have been fixed) and better in every way.

Comment: I'm also interested in the reason for this. I *can* imagine use cases, though. Would be nice if `JSON::XS|PP|...` had an option for that. In `YAML::PP` you can configure it, for example.

Comment: @tinita: `JSON::XS::Boolean` objects will behave nicely for things like `if $val == 1` but you shouldn't be using them that way. `if $val` or `unless $val` is proper Perl, and the objects behave properly there too. You can also `print "$val\n"` and get `1` or `0`. If anyone can find a way to distinguish between a `JSON::XS::Boolean` object and `1` or `0` (apart from `ref $val`) then you should say so as the intention is that they are indistinguishable.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, in most cases you shouldn't have to care, but there are cases where you'd want only plain values and no objects (e.g. passing to another serializer which doesn't want objects)

Comment: @dimorphus Also note, that newer versions of JSON::XS return JSON::PP::Boolean objects now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The values are blessed objects. They can only have the values allowed in JSON::XS::Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

With Cpanel::JSON::XS, the `unblessed_bool` option controls this. So, you could use the following:

```perl
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( );

my $j = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->utf8->unblessed_bool;

my $data = $j->decode( $json );
```

JSON::XS doesn't (currently) have an equivalent option. You would have to traverse the data returned structure and fix it up.